# How to get the data I want in MySQL in one query or in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

The table fields and its data:

```
auto_id   user_id  file_id
1         1         1
2         1         13
3         1         14
4         4         1
5         5         1
6         8         18
7         8         51
8         8         31
```

And what I want is:

```
userFiles[user_id] = 'file_id';
```

E.g:

```
userFiles[1] = '1,13,14';
userFiles[4] = '1';
userFiles[5] = '1';
userFiles[8] = '18,51,31';
```

Thank you very much!!

Comment: My way to get what I want was not elegant or effective.I use PHP to manipulate the data from MySQL and got what I want.So,I thought it must some way which much more effective to get it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(file_id)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY user_id
```

is the easy way to do it, if there aren't too many records - group_concat has a length limit of 1024 bytes (default, but is configurable).

Comment: It is great.I'll do more study on it!!  Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query you can use is straightforward for each ID:

"select file_id from TABLE where user_id = " . $user_id;

Load your answers into an array, then:

$string = implode(",",$answers);

Put the whole thing in a for loop around your user_id and assign to your userFiles array.